# OnClick element within specific element

Tags: jquery

I wish to know an elegant solution for clicking on a certain class within a certain div

```
$( ".clickdiv" ).on( "click", function () { //do stuff }
```

This works for any class of `clickdiv`. However, I want it only to work if the `clickdiv` is nested with `certain div`

```
<div class="certaindiv">
   ...bunch of divs
       <div class="clickdiv">
   ...bunch of close divs
<div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your selector as `.certaindiv .clickdiv` that it will only select `.clickdiv` inside `.certaindiv`

```js
$(".certaindiv .clickdiv").on("click", function() { 
  alert('clicked');
  //do stuff
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="certaindiv">
  ...bunch of divs
  <div class="clickdiv">
    shdhsghdh
  </div>
  ...bunch of close divs
</div>
<div class="clickdiv">
  shdhsghdh
</div>
```

Comment: Ugh friday afternoon strikes again... Thanks

Comment: @myol : glad to help ;)

Answer (score 1):

If the elements are on the page when it loads and never change, you can simply modify your selector:

```
$( ".certaindiv .clickdiv" ).on( "click", function () { /*do stuff*/ }
```

If the elements are dynamically created, you can use event delegation:

```
$( ".certaindiv" ).on( "click", ".clickdiv", function () { /*do stuff*/ }
```